# d3.js Zoomable Circle Packing - How to prevent additional click events until zoom is complete

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a Zoomable Circle Packing Visual where the pattern is pretty much identical to  [\Mike Bostock's version]](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-circle-packing). However, I'd like to be able to prevent additional clicks from kicking off a zoom if a current zoom is taking place.

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward, but I'm having no luck. I have a flag that indicates the beginning of the tween and another indicator for the end of the tween. I tried setting pointer-events to 'none' for the svg and all nodes (circles) at the beginning of the tween, and then turning them back to 'auto' at the end of the tween, but that did not alter the behavior.

[Mike Bostock's version](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-circle-packing)

Desired result: ZoomTo cannot be interrupted
Actual results: ZoomTo is interrupted with additional clicks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the same approach that you mention. [Here](https://observablehq.com/@garciaguillermoa/zoomable-circle-packing) is a fork of Mike Bostock's example

Here is what we did:

Create a variable called `zoomActive` and set it to false.

```
let zoomActive = false;
```

Check for `zoomActive` value in the SVG `click` event to prevent zooming out:

```
  .on("click", () => {
      if(zoomActive === false) {
        zoom(root)
      }
    }
  );
```

Check for `zoomActive` value in the circles `click` event to prevent zooming out:

```
  .on("click", 
    (d) => {
      if(zoomActive === false) {
        focus !== d && (zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation())
      }
    }
  );
```

Finally, update the value when the transition starts and end:

```
    .on('start', function() {
      zoomActive = true;
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      zoomActive = false;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow, I was way over thinking it. I also forgot that I had a click event on the div that contains my chart and wasn't incorporating logic in there to only zoom if not currently zooming. Again, thank you!